# Direct/silent printing in android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I want to send pdf document to the printer for printing directly (without showing system android preview )in my ionic app. How can I do it?
Currently, I'm using Cordova-plugin-printer to print pdf. As per the plugin's documents, direct printing is possible for iOS but not for android. Is there any plugin that supports direct printing in android? does android allow to print without print preview?